# How do you load a Bolex H-16?

Tags: setup, camera

How do you load a Bolex H-16?

A complete answer will include a link to the camera manual, page number for reference in the ASC manual, and a video demonstrating effective loading technique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following resources show how to load a Bolex H-16 camera:

[Instructional video for loading a Bolex (4 mins, Vimeo.com)](http://vimeo.com/5021853)

[PDF of the manual (see page 13 - "Feeding the film into-the camera by hand")](http://www.temple.edu/sct/fma/pdf/filmmaking/manuals/Bolex.pdf)

You can also find instructions on loading this camera in the American Cinematographer Manual.